# Docker container does not receive new files (updates) when rebuilding container that has a named volume

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have a dockercontainer that i build using a dockerfile via a docker-compose. I have a named volume, on the first build, it copies a file into /state/config

all is well, while the container is running, the /state/config receives more data because of a process I have running

the volume is setup like so

```
    volumes:
      - config_data:/state/config
```

on the dockerfile i use the copy like so

```
COPY --from=builder /src/runner /state/config/runner
```

So, as I say the first run - when no docker container or volume exists, then the /state/config recevies the "runner" file and also adds data into this same directory while the container is running.

Now I don't wish to destroy the volume, but if i rebuild the container using docker build or docker-compose build --no-cache then the volume stays - which is what i want but the runner is NOT updated.

I even tried to exec into the container and remove runner and then rebuild the container again and now the copying of the file does not even happen.

I wondered why this happening ?

Of course, I think i may have a work around, to place the file inside the docker container using the temporary volumes and not a named volume meaning the next time it is re-created then the file is recopied.

But I am confused why - its happening

Anybody help ?